# Find Event Locations Near User

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I built a mobile app that needs to locate events going on around them based on their current latitude and longitude with a 10 mile radius. The user clicks on an event type and the API needs to search for all events within 10 miles of them. The way my database is set up each event belongs to a venue and that is where the latitude and longitude is stored. Here is the SQL that I have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT events.*, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(78.3232)) * cos(radians($latitude)) * cos(radians($longitude) - radians(65.3234)) + sin(radians(78.3232)) * sin(radians($latitude)))) AS distance
    FROM events 
        INNER JOIN venues ON events.venue_id = venues.id 
        INNER JOIN promoters ON events.promoter_id = promoters.id 
    WHERE type = $type AND end > NOW()
    ORDER BY distance";
```

The events table stores information about an event (name, description, start, end, etc.) while the venues table stores information about a venue (name, address, latitude, longitude, etc.). How would I join these tables to make sure that I retrieve the events that I want based on the user's location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I edited the query to include table prefixes which will allow the math to pull the lat and long columns from the venues table.**  I checked this against my database and it works just fine as well.

Bou're not including a distance parameter in your criteria, using HAVING lets you include the `distance` column in your query criteria.  Your query would presumably return all events of $type that haven't happened yet. I checked this against a user table I have with lat and long and it works just fine.

It looks like you'd need something more like this (assuming you actually need all the columns from all three tables):

```
SELECT *, acos(cos(radians($userlat)) * cos(radians(`v`.`lat`)) * cos(radians(`v`.`long`) - radians($userlong)) + sin(radians($userlat)) * sin(radians(`v`.`lat`))) * 3959 AS `distance` 
    FROM `events` AS `e` 
        INNER JOIN `venues` AS `v` ON `e`.`venue_id` = `v`.`id`  
        INNER JOIN `promoters` AS `p` ON `e`.`promoter_id` = `p`.`id`  
    WHERE `e`.`type` = $type
    AND `e`.`end` > NOW() 
    HAVING `distance` < 25 
    ORDER BY `distance` ASC 
    LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I see that I was missing that HAVING clause. I think my difficulty is coming because the coordinates for each event are stored in the venues table. I need to grab the event information for all venues that are within that distance. I will continue to play with it. Would it be best if I posted my DB schemas?

Comment: The schemas would make it easier, and as frustrating as it is, listing out the columns you actually need would help.  I'm going to edit my post with another thought about that.

Comment: I actually just made the changes and saw how you were referring to the user input lat/lng versus the DB lat/lng and your edit should work. I'm going to do some testing on this but it should work perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm actually going to change my site to use this kind of query now.  So thanks for the idea!!